# Move button with css

Tags: css, html

How do I get the button next to textbox with css?

**Html code**

```
  <div data-bind="text:name" class="my-name"></div>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <input class="my-input"/>                   
  </div>             
  <div data-bind="dxButton: { icon: 'user' }"></div>
```

**css code**

```
.my-name{float:left;color:#fd9802;position: absolute}
.my-input{margin:0 auto 0 30%;display:block;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set *float* on same level elements (e.g. on the wrapper and not the input) and on every element (e.g. on the button as well)

```css
.my-name {
  float: left;
  color: #fd9802;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 0 30%;
  float: left;
}
.my-button {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div data-bind="text:name" class="my-name">Name</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <input class="my-input" />
</div>
<div data-bind="dxButton: { icon: 'user' }" class="my-button">Button</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS like this, remove auto and set the right margin o

```
.my-name{float:left;color:#fd9802;}
.my-input{margin:0 0 0 30%;display:block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.my-name{float:left;color:#fd9802;position: absolute}
.my-input{margin:0 auto 0 30%;display:block;}
 #wrapper{display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the + after the selector of the previous item

```
div#wrapper + div{
    /*css code*/
}
```